# Meteor: Trying to run my app in my device gives dependency error

Tags: android, meteor

I am trying to run my test meteor app into my device, but when I try to upload it, the console outputs the following error.

```
~ meteor run android-device --mobile-server mytest.meteor.com
[[[[[ ~/projects/simple-todos ]]]]]           

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           

WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile app to be able to connect to the local server, make sure your device is on the same network, and that the network configuration allows clients to talk to each other (no
         client isolation).
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
   Error: Command failed: /home/dbugger/projects/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run --device
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
   Required by:
   :android:unspecified
   > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
   > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
   > Failure initializing default system SSL context

   * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

   /home/dbugger/projects/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
   throw e;
   ^
   Error code 1 for command: /home/dbugger/projects/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew with args:
   cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/dbugger/projects/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:137:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

ExitWithCode:1
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I cant even add the `--stacktrace` flag to the command, as the output tells me to.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**: In case it matters, I am using **Ubuntu**

**UPDATE 2**: I installed the certificates on my System, but now I have another error!

```
   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
   Required by:
   :android:unspecified
   > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
   > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
   > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
   > peer not authenticated
```

Comment: I have same problem on a laptop (desktop is fine).  I think [`Failure initializing default system SSL context`](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/failure-initializing-default-system-ssl-context/6568) is the key to it, but haven't gone any further.

Comment: I copied `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` from my desktop to my laptop, and am now able to build on both systems.

Comment: That folder is empty for me.... I dont know if that is important... but every time I open Android Studios I get a message telling me that Google Certificate is untrusted... Maybe I have some permission problem with my folders?!?!?!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java`

Comment: Already installed...

Comment: Normally this is bundled with a java install.  Probably best to reinstall java.

Comment: Mmmpgh, now I have a problem with Maven... I have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I don't know why this worked, but it did. Just issue the following command:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

Comment: Wow, after trying dozens of complex solutions, this is what solved the problem